# jQuery - accessing parent <li> five levels up the hierarchy by $(this)

Tags: jquery, dom, this, hierarchy

I have a nested structure:

```
<li id="RCL137_1" class="rcl137">
  <table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <img id="RCDEL137_1" class="icon_rcdel" src="images/icon_delete.png">
```

If the image is $(this), is there an easy way to reference the line it belongs to without using the ID?  (For example, parent li something something...) I could do it by parent().parent()... but there has to be a neater way.

BTW: I have been doing it by ID, but I want to add a class event handler akin to the following:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.icon_rcdel', function (e) {
    $(this). [navigate to li] .remove();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

see http://api.jquery.com/closest/

and http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Magnificent. Works perfectly. I'll tick when the wait time elapses.